# Sentry not showing exception in web UI with logger.exception()

Tags: python-2.7, sentry

In our flask app, Sentry shows exceptions WITH stack trace in the web UI for uncaught exceptions like so:

`a = 1/0`

However in caught exceptions using the logger like so:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception('OH NOS occured: ')
```

The sentry UI only shows the logged message and no stack trace.

With regards to Sentry best practices (in python as well):

- Do caught exceptions require `raven.client.captureException()` below a info/warn/error log?
- Should `logger.error('msg', exc_info=True) be used instead?

Looking into the JSON being sent `"sentry.interfaces.Exception"` Isn't even part of the JSON body but it still sends the message to be logged.

Additional info (10/27/17):

File structure setup:

```
flask_app/
|--app
|--utils
```

in the logging config dict BOTH the app and utils loggers include a handler defined as sentry. Now here is where it gets interesting. In file utils.crasher I have:

```
import logging

logger = getLogger(__name__)

def crash_boy():
    try:
        1 + '123'
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception('Oh gosh we messed up big time here')
        raise e
```

and in app.main

```
@bp.route('/crash')
def crash():
    try:
        return crash_boy()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception('OH GREAT')
        return 'WE HAD A CRASH BOIZ'
```

Sentry will show the exception message and stack trace from the utils logger but the app logger will ONLY log the error message (`OH GREAT`).

Answer (score 2):

By default, Python logging does not capture the stack trace.

Per [the `logging` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#logging.debug):

> The second optional keyword argument is *stack_info*, which defaults to `False`. If true, stack information is added to the logging message, including the actual logging call.

Try instead:

```python
logger.exception('OH NOS occured: ', stack_info=True)
```

---

Do you need to invoke `raven.client.captureException()` "manually"? It depends on how you've configured it, but if you've used the recommended implementation for Flask ([as documented here](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/flask/)), then no:

> Once you’ve configured the Sentry application it will automatically capture uncaught exceptions within Flask.

Comment: Hmm, stack_info seems to only be a kwarg in debug (I should have also specified this is python 2.7 so it's not even a valid kwarg in that version

Comment: @Erik ["The arguments are interpreted as for `debug()`."](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#logging.exception)

Comment: Using `logging.exception('Exception encountered', traceback.format_exc())` will give you a more useful stack trace (potentially)

Comment: @JacobBudin `stack_info` is _already_ `True` when using `logging.Logger.exception()`. OP is _not_ using `debug()` which you are describing.

> [The arguments are interpreted as for debug(), except that any passed exc_info is not inspected. Exception info is always added to the logging message.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.exception)

(this is also true for Python 3)

Comment: @Florian `stack_info` is not the same as `exc_info`. I'm having same problem in Python 3.9. I haven't tested this solution yet but we can see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1517) (or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.18/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1202) in 2.7) that `logger.exception` only sets `exc_info=True` and not `stack_info=True`... so if Sentry needs that to display a properly formatted traceback then this answer is correct I guess.